# I'm using Flask and I want to insert an item to a DynamoDB table, what should the endpoint_url be?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have DynamoDB and my table defined as this:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-2', endpoint_url="https://dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com")

table = dynamodb.Table('Customers')
```

and after doing some processing, I'm able to programmatically get the values for this 4 attributes. Once a button is clicked (and executes some other operations that in the end return a URL) I want to call this table.put_item function. However, I'm getting a 500 internal server error.

```
table.put_item(
    Item={
            'Name': name,
            'Active': active,
            'Amount': amount,
            'Key': key
        }
    )
```

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.Summary.html) basically suggest that the endpoint should be this one, but I'm surely missing something because I must somehow specify that it should point to my DynamoDB table.

**Note:** The tutorial I linked to does ask to run `aws configure`and insert my keys. However, first, I'm putting my keys and it's failing to authenticate. Second, the Flask app that I want to add this function to is deployed in an Elastic Beanstalk instance, therefore I need to find the way to link this for the general purpose and not just for local testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not specify an endpoint if you're talking to the real DynamoDB service. It's only relevant for [DynamoDB Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html), a local, self-contained DynamoDB simulator for local testing (to reduce costs of running against the real DynamoDB and/or to develop locally without the need for an internet connection).

Just do something like the following (to talk to the real DynamoDB service in us-east-2):

```
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-2')
table = dynamodb.Table('Customers')
```

Comment: Got it. So how do I communicate the real service with the deployed app?

Comment: @EstebanVargas I have added sample code and hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, and just in case, the IAM security credentials do need to be in place no matter what

Comment: @EstebanVargas well you can't authenticate to DynamoDB without credentials.